# What do しよう and しよっ mean in this page?

Tags: colloquial-language, manga

These are the sentences I am confused about.  For better context, this is the [whole page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBPW1.jpg):

1. しよう in 「じゃあ今日は普通においしいものにしよう」
2. しよっ in 「…なににしよっかなぁー…」

Comment: These `よ`'s in the page are not small `ょ`.

Comment: @naruto You're right.    I have now edited the question. I apologize, I copy pasted it from a transcript in bilingual-manga.com, did not notice, and got confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> じゃあ今日は普通においしいもの**にしよう**

This にしよう is the volitional form of にする. The same にする used for making choices in, for example, a restaurant order. コーヒーにします = I'll have/choose/make it coffee.

The volitional form turns it into "let's have/choose/make it..."

So the girl is saying:
"Lets have something with an ordinary level of tastiness today." (the shop doesn't have anything **super**-tasty).

> なに**にしよっ**かなぁー

I think this しよっ is exactly the same as above: "I wonder what we'll have/choose?". My guess is that truncating しよう to しよっ makes it sound more chirpy/lively, but I'm far from certain about that.

Comment: According to definition 2-2 here https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%99%AE%E9%80%9A, 「普通においしい」 DOES mean "super-tasty".  Do you just have to distinguish the definition from context?

Comment: @Hikonyan Interesting find. I didn't know about that usage. Maybe this is all a hilarious pun and I've missed it. I think it would be worth asking a separate question about this.